# Git - How do I set the gitproxy, to use no proxy for the intranet and to use a proxy for the rest

Tags: git, proxy, git-submodules, intranet

I am using Git over an intranet. So, to access the intranet's repositories, I do not need a proxy. To access remote sub modules, I need to go through a proxy.

I can not use the gitconfig global _proxy settings ( _proxy = my.proxy.address ). If I set the proxy globally, I can't access the intranet.

My current approach is to use gitproxy entries under [core].

```
gitproxy = none for my.intranet.address
gitproxy = my.proxy.address
```

But that does not work. For now I am out of Ideas.

o What am I doing wrong?
o Is there an easier way?

Kudos in advance. \o/ \o/

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set the proxy on a per remote basis

```
[remote "origin"]
url = http://intranet.mycompany.com/git/my-git-repo
proxy =
```

From the top of my head, this can be done with the following command

```
git config origin.proxy ""
```